# Why the return value of stdout.channel.recv_exit_status is '7' instead of '0'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

Here is the python code that I use from paramiko shell package, the return value r is `7` instead of `0`. However if I run the same command in remote shell, and `echo $?`, it returns `0`

```
cmd = "curl --fail -s \"http://localhost:%s/\" > /dev/null" %HTTP_PORT
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    r = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
print "r is is %d" %(r)    #it returns '7'
```

Comment: Check what's in `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I tried the same set of commands but get `0`. Can you: 1. remove `--fail -s` and `> /dev/null` from the cmd, 2. print `stdout` and `stderr`?

Comment: @whjm, both **stdin** and **stderr** gives same as **stdout**, all of them return '7'

Comment: @hansaplast, all of them returns 7

Comment: Actually it sometimes return 0 and sometimes return 7, and I don't even know what does 7 means in exist code..

Comment: Remove `--fail -s` and `print 'stdout: %s, stderr: %s' % (stdout.read(), stderr.read() )`.

Comment: @georgewhr: you need to provide more information here, otherwise there's no chance of helping. Did you try what whjm and me were saying? What was the result?

Comment: btw: exit code 7 is not defined (at least not in `/usr/include/sysexits.h`), in [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74450/start-daemon-fails-with-exit-code-7) it is claimed by someone that it means `Program is not running` but IMO that is speculative..

Comment: I found the issue.. It's due to web service is not running at that period of time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that web server is not fully up during that period of time.